# Problem authenticating with gmail on Android

Tags: java, android, xml, authentication

Cannot authenticate with Google on Android. Android Studio shows these errors:
The following classes could not be instantiated:

```
com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
```

Here is my XML

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and here is my app gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ramadanapp.android.firebaseuploadimage"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: add `build.gradle` file with question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added dependency in build.gradle file at project level? If not then add the below dependency in that.

```
dependencies{
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    ...
}
```

Comment: my project depency has: classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

Comment: Thanks very much. The above answer solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i think you didn't add the dependencies of **play-services-auth**

Just add compile  `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.0'` `dependencies` in `build.gradle` app file like below code

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.0'
}
```

Comment: I have added it sir but still the rendering shows the same message.

Comment: try to **clean-ReBuild** your project @AbdellahRamadan

Comment: Already added : compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.0'

Comment: @NileshRathod I have cleaned and rebuilt the project. I don't know where the problem comes from. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @NileshRathod yes I still have the same error. I have added all the dependecies but nothing.